# Silverlight Extension Methods in Class Library

Tags: silverlight, extension-methods

I've implemented some extension methods as defined [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/vb-net-adding-containsany-and-containsal-2). I've put these into a separate assembly - Brandon.Extensions. It builds against the Silverlight runtime. I have a Silverlight application in which I would like to use these extension methods. I have added a reference to the Brandon.Extensions project from my Silverlight project - no problems. However, I can't get the extensions to show up. On the page I want to use an extension method on I start typing `Imports Brandon.Extensions` at the top of the code page, and no intellisense appears for that namespace.

I'm not sure if this is a Silverlight issue or an issue with extensions in general. How do I get those extension methods to be usable in the Silverlight app?

Notes:
Inside the Brandon.Extensions project, the root namespace is Brandon.Extensions, and the Module which holds my extensions is named IEnumerableExtensions. The Silverlight project is named Brandon.SilverlightApp and the root namespace is the same.

Comment: Are either of the projects signed with a strong name key?

Comment: No they are not signed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just had the module defined with no access modifier, so it defaulted to "Friend." I changed it to "Public" instead, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your Extensions project from the "Silverlight Class Library" new project template, and not the "Silverlight Application" template.

Jim

Comment: Yeah that's how I created it.